# Rails 4 / Filterrific gem - Problem with boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, filterrific

In my application, I have a field called `tested` which is a `boolean` field.

What I want to achieve is a simple `checkbox` where users can check or uncheck & filter based on `tested`.

In My model I have:

```
filterrific :default_filter_params => { :sorted_by => 'created_at_desc' },
              :available_filters => %w[
                sorted_by
                search_query
                with_created_at_gte
                with_tested
              ]
scope :with_tested, lambda { |flag|
    return nil  if 0 == flag # checkbox unchecked
    where(tested: true)
}

/// Other scopes
```

and In my view/form I have:

```
= f.check_box :with_tested
```

In my model I have also tried different approaches with no luck:

```
scope :with_tested, lambda { |value|
  where('posts.tested = ?', value)
}

// and 

scope :with_tested, lambda { |query|
  return nil  if 0 == query # checkbox unchecked
  where('posts.tested == ?', query)
}

// and

scope :with_tested, lambda { |flag|
    return nil  if 0 == flag # checkbox unchecked
    where(tested: [flag])
}
```

When I try to filter based on `tested`, I can see that my filter is trying to filter *(I see the filter spin)*, but my records are not filtered correctly.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong. Any suggestion and help is appreciated!

*All other parts of the filter work fine*

*PS: I haven't added `with_tested` in my controller as I got to know I don't need it*

---

*Versions:*

Ruby on Rails: 4.2.4

Filterrific: 2.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `where(tested: [flag])`, because it hasn't been *set* to `true` or `false`. To fix the issue `where` should *know* what the `value` is in *that case*.

So `where(tested: [flag])` should be changed to: `where(tested: true)` or `where(tested: false)`.

First, you need to specify this in your `model`:

```
scope :with_tested, lambda { |flag|
      return nil  if 0 == flag # checkbox unchecked
      where(tested: true)
    }
```

In your `view` do the following:

```
= f.check_box :with_tested
```

and add `:with_tested` in your controller in `available_filters`.

*PS: Code has been tested and works*